# Method of avoiding variant Greek letters

Tags: greek

Using a virtual greek keyboard and the following packages it's possible to directly implement Greek unicode characters (e.g. θ)

```
\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

However the displayed characters in the PDF are always the Greek variants e.g. `\vartheta` as opposed to `\theta`.

Is there any way to avoid this other than `\let\vartheta\theta` for each character?

Answer (score 9):

hmmmm

The Unicode definitions for theta are:

```
U+03b8 GREEK SMALL LETTER THETA

U+03d1 GREEK THETA SYMBOL
```

With the first of those being the one in your question, and the second being the more curly open one.

However in the encodings set up by  the `ucs` package a U+03b8 character will by default give you `\texttheta` (which would probably give you the right character in text mode if you loaded the correct font encodings, I got undefined command) But if you use the `[mathletters]` option as in your fragment it switches to use the definition

```
\uc@dclc{952}{mathletters}{\ensuremath{\vartheta}}%
```

in the file `uni-3.def`

I.e., assumes that you want the theta-symbol character in math mode. So the `\let` you suggest would be one way, or you could over-ride this definition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\uc@dclc{952}{mathletters}{\ensuremath{\theta}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

 (e.g. θ)

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

The full set of `\var`... in `uni-3.def` is

```
5 matches for "\\var" in buffer: uni-3.def
    174:\uc@dclc{949}{mathletters}{\ensuremath{\varepsilon}}%
    183:\uc@dclc{952}{mathletters}{\ensuremath{\vartheta}}%
    210:\uc@dclc{961}{mathletters}{\ensuremath{\varrho}}%
    213:\uc@dclc{962}{mathletters}{\ensuremath{\varsigma}}%
    225:\uc@dclc{966}{mathletters}{\ensuremath{\varphi}}%
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid ucs (which clashes e.g. with biblatex) you can use the lgrxenc.def and lgrenc.dfu provoided here: http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LGR/

lgrenc.dfu maps e.g. U+03BB to `\texttheta` which I think should be the symbol you want.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are using an outdated version of `ucs`. Starting with version 2.0 from April 2012, both normal and variant greek characters map to the proper macros when using the `mathletters` option. See my blog article [*New release of the ucs LaTeX package*](http://jeltsch.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/new-release-of-the-ucs-latex-package/).

If you have to stick to your older `ucs` version, you can also modify the mappings from characters to TeX code, which is cleaner than redefining the greek letter macros via `\let`. However, using `\uc@dclc`, as in the answer from David Carlisle, is not recommended. The user-level command to use is `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`. See [the package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ucs/ucs.pdf).